# Bad ssh config on remote server. Cannot login in

Tags: ssh, debian

I accidently changed ssh_config instead of sshd_config on a remote debian machine. Whenever i try to loging, i get

```
    /etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 55: Bad configuration option: permitrootlogin
    /etc/ssh/ssh_config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
```

How can i resolve this issue remotely?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To resolve this issue please comment out *line 55* in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`

```
#PermitRootLogin yes
```

`PermitRootLogin` is actually an option which would be valid in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file; not the `ssh_config` file. The difference is that the `sshd_config` file controls the SSH server ("d" in "sshd" is from "daemon") and the `ssh_config` file controls *the client*. Therefore, it would indeed be a bad (invalid) config option in the client settings file.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to do it remotely!
Just delete permitrootlogin line from *local* /etc/ssh/ssh_config file which used during ssh connection to a remote server.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you can't log into the system, you're going to have to boot in rescue mode, or access it via console, if that is an option.

But ssh_config is the config file that is used by the ssh client, sshd_config is used by the ssh server. If you try to log into the server, that server should be reading sshd_config. Did you change something in the ssh_config file of your local machine?

Answer (score 0):

This exact file (SSH *client* config) is not usually needed on the server side, and the problem won't appear unless you are chaining SSH connections (using a server-side client to connect to another server). Assuming the `sshd_config` exists and `ssh_config` is a (partial) copy of it, then you can safely move aside the latter, e.g. by:

```
$ sudo mv /etc/ssh/ssh_config /etc/ssh/ssh_config.bak
```

If you however need to set up the SSH client config (on that server), see the [docs](https://linuxize.com/post/using-the-ssh-config-file/).